# jquery click trigger really slow because of document ready and large DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I want to have both the **radio button checked** and **radio button click** event when the particular **table data cell** is clicked. I have achieved that using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").click(function(e) {
        var chk = $(this).closest("td").find("input:radio").get(0);
        if (e.target != chk) {
            chk.checked = !chk.checked;
        }
        var chkid = $(this).closest("td").find("input:radio").attr("id");
        $("#" + chkid).click();
    });
});
```

[image]

My `$("td").click()` function works only when i embed in **document ready**. But, since its triggering the click event only in **document ready**, its being triggered after 6 seconds or more. I need the click event because it is rendering `css` and all the **table data logic** is being rendered with the click. Any way to shorten this lag will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some html to this?

Comment: The html part doesn't have much.The table is being generated with the javascript and the table datas are being dynamically added using javascript aswell, inside the usercontrol. And, the functions are quite large and confusing in itself. So, if only i could reduce the delay of jquery document ready. It would be really helpful.

Comment: embedding the click trigger on document click solved the lagging for me. Thank you for the edit and desire to help :) . Hope my answer can help others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the cause for lag was using the click trigger on document ready. Embedding the click trigger on document click solved the lagging for me.

```
$(document).on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    var chk = $(this).closest("td").find("input:radio").get(0);
    if (e.target != chk) {
        chk.checked = !chk.checked;
    }
    var chkid = $(this).closest("td").find("input:radio").attr("id");
    $("#" + chkid).click();
});
```